# Garbage on RS232 and no the baudrate IS correct

Tags: serial, rs232, ftdi

I have a device like this https://www.vaisala.com/sites/default/files/documents/WXT530-Users-Guide-M211840EN.pdf.

**Some facts:**

- I have an FTDI to USB board from Sparkfun which is tested to work with other serial devices, so it's not broken.
- The device mentioned above is correctly wired for RS232 and is tested with an USB -> DB9 on 19200,8,N,1 to work correct both on Mac and Windows.
- The serial device prints ASCII characters one line at the time which is ended with `<crlf>`

**My problem:**

When I wire the serial device to the FTDI to USB and I use the correct baudrate, I get garbage out. I have spent numerous hours to fix this and I can't figure out the problem.

If someone have ideas, that would be appreciated.

**Things I have tried :**

1. I tried 2 different USB to DB9 that work fine both on Windows and Mac
2. I tried the mentioned FTDI from Sparkfun both on Mac and Windows, same problem -> garbage.
3. On the Vaisala device, I have connected SGND (Serial Ground) with the Vin - no difference.

My ultimate goal is to connect the Vaisala serial device to the serial of an ESP8266, but until I understand this problem I can't continue. Actually I did try to connect it and I also get garbage here too.

Comment: There is no such thing as an FTDI to USB board. There are, however, UART to USB boards and RS232 to USB boards using FTDI chips.

Comment: Did you check things like stop bits and start bits, parity, and other RS232 options?  Also, do you have or need flow control, and if so how is it implemented, hardware or software?

Comment: @DKNguyen, OP has a RS232 to USB adapter made by FTDI.

Comment: You can order that device with 3 different protocols on the RS232 line, two of them are simple (ASCII and NMEA) and one is much different, SDI. Do you know which one you have?

Comment: The linked user's guide is 222 pages. Please show an excerpt related to the serial communications interface that you are trying to use. Also, carefully check and list the **voltage levels** used by your FTDI board.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis YES i know the communcation settings are correct since i ran with same settings on two different UART to USB which have FTDI chipset inside them, i also tested this on both Mac and Windows. I have thought about Flow control but there is nothing specified in the manual that i need to do. I did however tried various settings inside serial communication software but no change.

Comment: @RonBeyer The unit is configurable yes and it has been configured to run RS-232 ASCII Auto and is found to be working fine with other UART to USB converters, my problem is with this Sparkfun UART to USB which btw works fine with other serial devices.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson yes i did think about that therefore i have tested the unit by providing 12V from a separate power supply to Vin since it requires minimum 6V to operate properly therefore i tied up the Vin- with the SGND.

Comment: If your USB adapter works on other devices then I'm starting to suspect a loose connection on the PCB, loose wiring, or simply the wrong baud rate settings (even though it tells you 19200, etc.) Perhaps you can start troubleshooting with other settings.

Comment: You could try scoping the RS-232 to see if anything @KingDuken says might be true.

Comment: @KingDuken I have checked more than 10 times that the baudrate are ok, they are default 19200,8,N,1. I have moved so many times between the different UART to USB devices and EVERY TIME it works on other UART to USB devices besides the Sparkfun AND the ESP8266 (both have same issue).

Comment: @DKNguyen yes that is my last resort, i would have to take it to work since i don't have a scope at home

Comment: @dbrasco No, we need to know the voltage levels for the **serial lines**, not the power supply voltage level. We also need to know the voltage levels for the "unit"...are they really RS-232 or some other voltage?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson You are saying something that made me thinking. The Sparkfun FTDI is 5V. Does that mean something ? I mean some UART to USB are 3V. Can i measure dirrectly on the serial line if between what ?

Comment: Give us the datasheet for the sparkfun FTDI device

Comment: I bought it many years ago but i think this is just a newer version of it https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9716

Update: here is the old one i have : https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10008

Comment: @dbrasco I suppose you could try sending a continuous alternating stream of ones and zeroes and see if your multimeter reads closer to 2.5V or 1.66V

Comment: It appears that the Sparkfun FTDI board uses "TTL" levels, rather than RS-232.  The TTL signal is inverted relative to RS-232.  The FTDI board is for use with Arduino and other devices that do not have the RS-232 line drivers that invert the signal.  USB->DE9 cables will normally have RS-232 line drivers.

Comment: @PeterBennett I guess that's why its important to accurately know/say whether you have a RS-232 to USB board or a UART to USB board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a USB to serial converter provides a serial interface that uses 5V or 3V TTL/CMOS voltage levels. The Vaisala device provides a serial interface that uses RS-232 voltage levels. These are incompatible. You need a USB to serial converter that also provides a serial interface with RS-232 voltage levels.

Comment: So i am not entirely sure, does that mean that i can't use the Sparkfun at all meaning i most likely have same issue with my ESP8266. Sine ESP is the end goal, what do i need, i need a middle man ?

Comment: To convert TTL/CMOS levels to RS-232 levels, you need a RS-232 tranceiver chip or ready made board that has one. I would guess these are available from any hobbyist shops, including the one you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you all, i know what to do now. Sorry if i have mislead you. Now i know the difference between TTL and RS232

Comment: @dbrasco: Have a look at my answer to [why-cant-i-successfully-send-messages-over-rs232](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/397062/why-cant-i-successfully-send-messages-over-rs232/397074#397074) which was very similar to yours. Notice the debugging and information that the poster supplied was much more specific than "garbage" and facilitated successful analysis of the problem.